# Chrome URL multiple spaces issue

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, urlencode

When we have a url with multiple spaces say `/partofurl  2014/index`, usually browsers encode it as `/partofurl%20%202014/index`.
But when i paste `/partofurl  2014/index` in chrome it treats multiple spaces as single and encodes the URL like this `/partofurl%202014/index` is there any way to stop chrome by doing so?

Answer (score 3):

There is an issue on Chromium project website: 
https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=361665

Its status is WontFix and there is an proposed solution - manual encoding spaces with percents:

> This is intentional.  Users copying and pasting text with whitespace into the omnibox are usually pasting from e.g. emails or other places where there may be arbitrarily long strings of whitespace, so we collapse them.  If you have a URL where you need multiple sequential space characters, percent-encode them.